# wget/curl do not write to file until download is completed

Tags: wget, curl

I am trying to run wget/curl every few seconds to cache a HTTP file that is constantly changing (dynamically generated file, different on each HTTP request).

- origin fetch is a bit slow (~10s) and expensive, that's why I would like to cache it and serve user requests right away. Mostly the time spent on HTTP digest authentication and waiting for server HTTP response (takes a few seconds to generate the response on server).
- the files are fairly small so I am downloading them to a tmpfs
- unable to use nginx for reverse proxy because the origin requires HTTP digest authentication (user --> HTTPS, no auth --> server --> HTTP, digest auth --> origin)

The problem is that wget/curl write to the file immediately while download is in progress (0 byte file for seconds while waiting for origin HTTP response). When the client access the cached file, I want to serve them the latest cached copy available, instead of a 0 byte file or half-completed download.

I tried `wget --backups 10` expecting to use filename.1 (at the cost of introducing a delay of 1 refresh cycle), but it doesn't seem to work with `-O` and no copy was saved (file gets overwritten every time).

Is there a better solution to serve the last cached copy?

Comment: You say you're downloading to a tmpfs.  Are you also serving clients from that same location?  That is, are you downloading the file into the same directory and same name that the clients are accessing?

Comment: If you read through [wgets manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) in point 2.5. you'll notice, that `-O` is not a qay to tell wget to simply save the downloaded file under a different name, but to place all of it's recieved (downloaded) content will be put there. I don't know if this helps you.

Comment: Yes currently serving clients from the same tmpfs location but this is not a requirement

Comment: I went through the man page and can't find another way to rename the file. The filename portion of the URL is the same for several requests so I need a way to distinguish them.

Comment: Why can't you simply download the file to an offline temporary directory, and after you've verified that the download was successful, move the newly-downloaded file into your webserver directory, overwriting the previous file there?  You may want to do that as a copy-then-rename operation to ensure that you don't have a similar race condition if a client requests the file just as you're copying it in there.

Comment: I switched to `curl -o` which waits download to start and does a buffered write (instead of `wget` of `curl > ` truncating the file right away), still not ideal but a huge improvement than having an empty file for 10s.

I am just trying to figure out a better way to do it (least operations).